# Why nobody replies to my flags?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, flags, moderation

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244066/jquery-validator-check-for-email-or-phone-in-one-input-field), due to I can't ask questions. I edited this downvoted and deleted question, changed the topic, and flagged this. In a day, nobody replied. I flagged it again. Silence. And again flagged. Silence. Why none of moderators replies?
 If moderator sees it, I ask him to pay attention to my question and reopen it. Also I ask to clear all comments.

Comment: Which flag did you use? If custom: What did you write into the flag?

Comment: @BDL "I ask to reopen this question. Also I ask to clear all comments."

Comment: Goto https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/9277191 and check your flag status

Comment: Your last edit completely changed the question. You were asking something about reading text files, now you are asking something about validation. I don't think this is how it's supposed to work. About the flag: In general, reopening is done by the community through the reopen review queue, not by moderators.

Comment: Moderators in general will not re-open a question. Deleting comments is something they might do, assuming the comments are obsolete. Don't mix two different requests in the same flag, You'll short-circuit the decision making process of the mod handling your flag, causing catastrophic failure. Of the moderator that is

Comment: @BDL This topic of an answer was really stupid, it is impossible to bring up question with such a topic.

Comment: Here is a screenshot for < 10K users:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWldx.png and here is the revision history:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DR3G.png

Comment: Moderators are human, they have a huge stack of flags to go through, and that's on top of other moderation duties, sleep, food, work, other human stuff. End result is that sometimes it takes a while to get to your flag, if my modflag is the only one against a post it can sometimes take 3-4 days for it to be handled. They'll get round to it eventually, but face a mountain of other work on here.

Comment: Also to chuck in my two pence on the question itself, it's too drastic a change in my opinion. Edits should fix content problems with a question/answer, but should not *fundamentally change* its content. In your case I believe this question should have been left alone to be deleted, and the edit posted as a new question.

Comment: @MichaelDodd they have to wait 6 months then as they are q-banned atm. Not convinced the *new* question is any good either. It lacks attempt / enough research. But they have time to fix that ...

Comment: You will also want to read this if you can't ask new questions: **[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)**

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/52244066) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/52225008) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/52131192) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/51882962) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/51819088) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/51669840) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/48600679))

Comment: Don't try to get around question bans. Editing a closed and deleted answer into a completely new question is not how SE is meant to work. You were banned for a reason. Not to mention, if somehow your question _were_ undeleted and reopened, you'd be starting off with a score of -10, and you'd probably get even more downvotes because of your bypass of the current content moderation systems.

Answer (score 11):

Your flags were "replied to". For future reference, here's your personal flag history: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/9277191?group=1

You can see both were declined as two different moderators did not see any need to take further action on your question. I won't paste the contents of the flags here -- should you want to discuss the decline reasons, feel free to include them as an edit to your question.